# Why Can't found this element with WebDriver?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am starting in the world of UI automation with WebDriver and Java. I am getting a problem when I try to select a element of a combo box. This is the code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://intersite.com/");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='term']"))); //Exception happens in this line org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='term']"}
```

And this is the code in the web site (I use Firepath to know the Xpath):

```
<select name="term" onchange="getTipDoc('');" id="term" class="termination"><option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
                            <option value="OPT1">Option 1</option>
<option value="OPT2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

I see in the tag select, the ID attribute is correct but the exception always happens. I tried with othe method for locate the element like "By.id" but doesn't work too. What can i do?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of possible reasons can happen in case like this

- Element you are looking for is inside an `iframe`. Use `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(somethting));`
- Element look up is faster than the load time. In this case use explicit wait. `WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("term")));` See [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)
- There are duplicate Ids. try using `select[id='term'][class='termination']` as cssSelector

And, of course use `By.id()` since the id is available.

Comment: Hello @Saifur, probably is the first point. What do you mean with "something"?

Comment: Something like `By.xpath`/`By.cssSelector()` etc

Comment: I am writing [code]driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("term")));[/code] But didn't work. :(

Comment: Well, that's not `iframe`. `iframe` is a tag that usually contains bunch of other tags. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: Yeah! I found a "frameset" in the source code, I switched to that and now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait to get the page load before trying to get its element this code will help you to do that

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='term']")));
```

Comment: Yes, I added a Thread.sleep(10000) before. i tried with your answer but the problem persists.